# Avoiding the "capturing self strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle" message

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

every time I have to use a global var or property inside a block like this:

```
self.save = ^(){
  if (isItSaving == NO) {
      [self saveMyFile];
  }
};
```

I have to rewrite this like

```
BOOL *iis = isItSaving;
id myself = self;

self.save = ^(){
  if (iis == NO) {
      [myself saveMyFile];
  }
};
```

or Xcode will complain "capturing self strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle...

It complains even about BOOL variables?

Redeclaring everything before a block appears to be a lame solution.

Is this the correctly way? Is there an elegant way?

This stuff is ugly. I am using ARC.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem only occurs when referencing `self` from within the block, explicitly or implicitly. There's no warning emitted when accessing global variables.

In your case you probably accessed a (boolean) ivar. Accessing the ivar implicitly uses `self`, that's why the compiler is warning you (correctly) about a retain cycle.

The common way to fix the retain cycle is:

```
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

self.save = ^() {
    typeof(weakSelf) __strong strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf != nil && ! strongSelf->isItSaving) {
        [strongSelf saveMyFile];
    }
};
```

... and, yes, that's a bit of an ugly part of blocks.

Comment: man, this is ugly as hell. Having to redeclare everything... thanks.

Comment: @MarkAmery Yes, clang catches more and more issues. And it's correct, the lifetime of the enclosing object should be extended at least until the block finishes. Editing...

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe *"the lifetime of the enclosing object should be extended at least until the block finishes"* - nice, I didn't at first notice any reason why creating a strong reference to `self` within the block would be preferable to using `__unsafe_unretained`, but that phrase alone makes it incredibly clear. Might even be worth comparing the two approaches in your answer, if you wished to.

Answer (score 4):

Use `__unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self;`

Comment: I think you cannot use __unsafe_unretained with ARC

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @NikolaiRuhe's response, in your example when declaring the properties

```
BOOL *iis = isItSaving;
id myself = self;
```

implies `strong` references, so use `__weak` self to prevent the retain cycle. Then you might wonder why you need to declare a `__strong` reference to weak self within the block, and that's to make sure it doesn't get released during the life of the block, otherwise `weakSelf->isItSaving` would break if `self` was released.